# VPN certificates always state "This certificate has an invalid digital signature." on one machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

While attempting to connect to the Windows Azure Virtual Network (and knowing all keys are installed), I always get the error message:

```
A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
 (Error 0x800b0109)
```

When I investigate my certificates, I see that my FunnelFire and Root Agency certificates are both station that "This certificate has an invalid digital signature".

I have several other machines setup with these keys and with the same VPN client install, and they all work fine. I am using windows 8.1 on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the certificate into your trusted root cert folder. This will make sure that the certificate gets registered and recognized properly.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked over 3 years ago, I would like to provide an answer for others that stumble across this same challenge.

Overview:
You'll need to import the .cer certificate into the local computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Steps:

1. Open the Azure VPN .exe file (I use 7-Zip)
2. Extract the .cer file
3. Import the .cer file into the local computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities
4. Connect to the Azure VPN